# Coderush Xpress commercial using

Tags: coderush-xpress

Can I use Xpress free version of Coderush in commercial work or this version is recommended for learning solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "commercial work". Am I right in my assumption that you mean using CodeRush Xpress while working on a commercial project?  If so, yes, you can certainly use it.  If you mean something else, please describe this in greater detail. Anyway, you'll get a better answer by contacting management@devexpress.com.

Comment: I have a job where I work as junior programmer and I use Visual studio 2010. Can I install and use in project  I write in my work Coderush Xpress?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use it.